# What does 6kV , 5MW 90% efficiency at full load with 0.9 Power Factor lagging represent for a motor?

Tags: power, three-phase, electrical, power-engineering

I am confused with I see such a statement like the following statetment:
 Motor with 6kV , 5MW 90% efficiency at full load with 0.9 Power Factor lagging.

Could anyone explain it in simple words ?

Comment: Take each chunk of information separately. For instance, what would 6 kV imply to you? If you can work that out, then move to the next chunk.

Comment: That would fall under 'education' which is not what we do here for good reasons. For example: we have no idea what your electronic background knowledge is, so we have no idea so where to start. Do you know how power is calculated? Do you know about voltage vs current phase shifts?

Answer (score 2):

5MW is the mechanical power the motor shaft puts out.

6kV is the source line voltage in to the motor.  What the motor needs to run at rated operation.

To get 5MW mechanical power out of the motor at an efficiency of 90%, means that 5MW + 10% electrical power must be put in (5.56MW).

$$ \eta = \frac {P_{out}}{P_{in}} \times 100%$$

Finally, the power factor (a little bit more complex).

The motor consists of a stator and rotor.  The stator has windings that create a magnetic field to cause the rotor to rotate. These windings are an inductive load \$X_L\$ and they consume reactive power \$Q_L\$.  So the source has to put in real power \$P_{in}\$ (MW) to drive the mechanical load and reactive power \$Q_L\$ (MVAR) to cause the motor to spin.  This power is called apparent power, S (MVA).

The power factor is a sort of efficiency of the motor/circuit.  Power out of motor vs what the source has to generate.

$$ pf = \frac {P_{in}}{S_{in}}$$

To get 5MW at 90% efficiency and 0.9 lagging power factor, the 6kV source supplies 6.17MVA of apparent power at current of 660A.

Answer (score 0):

you did not provide the rated rpm. given the large power rating, this makes me believe the motor is DC.

6kV would be the input voltage. I know large diggers use 5kV DC for their motors. obviously such a motor would come equipped with its own AC/DC converter.

5MW is the max mehcanical power output of the motor. given the large torque, expect that amount of mechanical power at up to max rpm which depends on the load.

the next two values are a bit confusing so ill try my best.

90% efficiency means the motor converts into mechanical power 90% of the electrical power absorbed (by the motor drive) from the grid; however the power factor 0.9 says the total energy absorbed by the motor drive from the grid represents only 90% of the energy supplied by the grid.

now to wrap it up: the overall efficiency of the motor is 81%. compare that to 13-21% of a piston engine or 30-40% of a jet engine.

Comment: Mentioning a "0.9 Power Factor" is to me a strong suggestion that we are talking about an AC motor.

Comment: not necessarily. dont forget the DC drive which for a 5MW motor is very large.

Comment: "*... the power factor 0.9 says the total energy absorbed by the motor drive from the grid represents only 90% of the **apparent** energy supplied by the grid.*" (You missed an important word.) The energy absorbed the motor has to equal the energy supplied by the grid or else some energy has vanished. The power factor of an AC electrical power system is defined as the ratio of the real power absorbed by the load to the apparent power flowing in the circuit. [Power factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor).

Comment: I believe my answer is clear enough without your comment. Let’s keep the focus on answering rather than on trolling the forum.

Comment: @Oldfart I disagree. An induction machine is closer to 0.8 DPF while a Sync machine can easily be 0.91.

Comment: We’re talking 5MW motor. Not sure if you understand that

Comment: The motor can be DC, but the power factor implies an ac source, so there would have to be an AC to DC converter (or VFD) with a lagging power factor driving your DC motor.

Comment: That is exactly what I’ve mentioned in my answer. Thank you for repeating that.